# CSS positioning, hidden part of div

Tags: css, web, styles, positioning

I've a problem with css positioning. I would like to display the same web page on my tablet device as on my PC. On PC I'm using Chrome web browser and everything works fine, but when I'm trying to display the same content on Safari web browser on my tablet device, then I obtain the same result as on the attached screen (part of my div content is hidden by the external element). What is the cause of this behaviour? Any ideas? CSS for DIV ELEMENT is:

```
position: fixed; max-height: 300px; width:200px; overflow:auto; z-index: 100000
```

Attached situation on:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkYp2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Changing that from `overflow: auto` to `overflow: visible` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Josh for answer, but it didn't resolve my problem. It was caused by:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

All my divs had this global setting which caused this strange behaviour on mobile devices.
We can read, that is native-style scrolling. Specifying this style has the effect of creating a stacking context (like opacity, masks, and transforms).